# DB2: update get "Error applying transforms. Verify that the specified transform paths are valid."

Tags: db2, upgrade, updates

I have a:

1. Windows 2019 server
2. IBM DB2: Version 11.5.0
3. "v11.5.7_ntx64_universal_fixpack"

I want to update the DB to Version 11.5.7 with this "v11.5.7_ntx64_universal_fixpack".

a.) I doublclick the "setup.exe"

b.) On the launchpad, I choose under "Install Product", working with an existing installation

c.) then I choose my Edition and click button to start

==> I get the message: *"Error applying transforms.  Verify that the specified transform paths are valid."*

In the log I have the following text:

*DEBUG: Error 2254:  Database:  Transform: Cannot update row that doesn't exist. Table: Property
1: 2254 2:  3: Property
Error applying transforms. Verify that the specified transform paths are valid.
C:\Windows\Installer\2641882f.mst
MSI (c) (B4:44) [11:15:10:831]: Produkt: DB2 Server Edition -- Installation fehlgeschlagen.

MSI (c) (B4:44) [11:15:10:831]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: DB2 Server Edition. Product Version: 11.5.7000.1973. Product Language: 1031. Manufacturer: IBM. Installation success or error status: 1624.*

I search for a solution some day but have found nothing. Has somebody an idea or an idea?

thank you

Regards

Tino

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have found the solution myself:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/applying-db2-v115-fix-pack-windows-fails-error-applying-transforms-any-language-other-english

In my system, the path was another. I have found the correct path to the files with regedit, and now the update works perfectly.